# TFS Agent idle/offline at Deploy test agent task

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

TFS 2015 update 3 test agent goes idle/sleep every time I queue a build. I have automated UI build running test on my system itself. I have to manually refresh the agent every time.
Couple of other issues-

1.Access is denied error with WinRM even though nothing has been changed. This comes in subsequent runs. Will have to delete and re configure agent from start when this happens.
2.Agent is locked or sleep.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "agent goes idle"? Are you talking about the computer on which the agent is installed?

Comment: When I look in Agent pool, it is shown as red. It doesn't respond when I queue build. I have agent installed on my system itself and it runs as an interactive process.

Comment: Is there any error message display on the interactive process?

Comment: `Authenticating to the server http://abc/tfs
 CentralLogger.Listen() - waiting for shutdown
 Created Session: 40b88fd4-225f-4a06-810f-9df05e701623
MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - starting loop
 MessageQueueListener.DispatchAsync - Getting message from Session: 40b88fd4-225f-4a06-810f-9df05e701623
 Waiting for Escape key on background thread: True
 Waiting for shutdown request event on background thread: True`

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I don't see any error messages apart from any suspicion on the above shutdown